# Search bar works correctly but crashes when I want to set table cell label

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar

I am trying to implement a search bar with my table view. Both my table view and search bar are placed using storyboard. In my ViewDidLoad, I have:

```
self.searchDisplayController.delegate = self;
self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsDataSource = self;
self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsDelegate = self;
```

and implemented two search methods:

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    NSPredicate *bPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"nickname contains[cd] %@",searchText];
    NSArray* array = [[NSArray alloc]init];
    array = [self.fbfriendList filteredArrayUsingPredicate:bPredicate];
    self.searchResult = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:array];
}
-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles] objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];
    return YES;
}
```

In my table view method:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"addFriend";

    cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"FFAddFriendTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}
if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
{
    NSLog(@"!!! %@",self.searchResult);
    if (cell == nil) {
         [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"FFAddFriendTableViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"addFriend"];
    }
    else{
    NSLog(@"!!! %@",self.searchResult);
 // LINE XXXXXXX
        cell.nameLabel.text = [[self.searchResult objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"nickname"]; 
    }
}
else
{
}
cell.nameLabel.text = [[self.fbfriendList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"nickname"];
return cell;
}
```

Everything works accordingly in terms of search. My NSLogs prints out the correct data in my array. However, when I want to set the cell's label according to the data from the NSMutableArray, it crashes with the error:

```
-[__NSCFString setText:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ff38b5b70e0
```

Am I missing any crucial fundamental to implementing the search bar to my tableView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

now change your table view  cellrowindex Method to this..

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"addFriend";

    cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"FFAddFriendTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        cell.nameLabel.text = [[self.searchResult objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"nickname"];
    } else
    {
       cell.nameLabel.text = [[self.fbfriendList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"nickname"];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the line below "// LINE XXXXXX", you have,

```
cell.nameLabel = ...
```

That should be,

```
cell.nameLabel.text = ...
```

Comment: rookie mistake by me. I've changed it to cell.nameLabel.text. It doesn't crash now but it doesn't display the correct cell. If there are 2 results, the table will only display the first two cell from my main table. Am I missing something?

Comment: @EricChuang, I'm not sure I understand your problem. If there are only 2 results, you should only see 2 cells in the search results table.